# Would Epoptes work in a classroom of Ubuntu 16.04 machines which are in a Windows domain?

Tags: 16.04, networking, edubuntu

In my classroom, I have 17 Ubuntu 16.04 workstations plus my own Ubuntu 16.04 machine. They are all members of a Windows Domain. Epoptes is a classroom management tool that enables the teacher to see the student's screen and manage some simple functions on their computer. Epoptes is part of the Edubuntu distribution and normally works as part of an LTSP network with the teacher's computer as a server. Do you think it would be possible to get Epoptes to work in my environment with the Ubuntu computers linked by a Windows AD domain rather than LTSP?

Comment: What is "Epoptes"?

Comment: This? https://github.com/Epoptes/epoptes But it would help if you explain what you want to use it for. Help us to help you, etc

Comment: You probably can run Linux machines on the same network just the may need separate configuration (I assume you may want to use existing user info off the Windows network, it can be done for some things I think). Epoptes is included in the repos @Zanna https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=zesty&searchon=names&keywords=Epoptes https://screenshots.debian.net/package/epoptes

Comment: The main website for [Epoptes](http://www.epoptes.org/) indicates that it works with Ubuntu, and Epoptes is already a [package available for Ubuntu 17.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=epoptes&searchon=names&suite=zesty&section=all)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does work, you need to install epoptes-client on each machine and then edit the /etc/hosts file to add the epoptes server as a server with the correct IP address. The ubuntu machine will then be visible to and controlled by the epoptes server.